# XAMPP MySQL server won't start on Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: mysql, terminal

I've spent several days on this problem, I've been searching the forums / Google to see if anyone has a solution. I need to run an older version of XAMPP (5.6) and the MySQL server fails to start on Mac OS X. The XAMPP application manager will not start the MySQL server, so I used Terminal

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server start
```

to force the server to run. But I got an error message:
"Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysqld_safe_helper: Can't create/write to file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/UserName.local.err' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server: line 260: kill: (3256) - No such process
ERROR!"

Get the same error when logging into Terminal as ROOT.

The privileges for the "UserName.local.err" file was:
-rwxrwx---   1 UserName  admin   2500041 Oct 28 16:22 UserName-MacBook-Pro.local.err

So I gave the file all privileges - I will delete the entire XAMPP folder (a copy) after printing out the SQL table structure and data.

The privileges for the file are now:
-rwxrwxrwx   1 UserName  admin   2500041 Oct 28 16:22 UserName-MacBook-Pro.local.err

The error message has now changed a bit:
"Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server: line 260: kill: (4738) - No such process
ERROR!"

Any idea as to getting this server to run? Thanks so much for your help!
Cheers,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is odd. I cycled through the steps (and the problem) over and over again. I re-installed the old version of XAMPP a number of times and had the same issue. I re-installed it one last time, and the mysql.server started up. Can't say why though...

Thanks anyway,
Rick

Comment: MySQL from XAMPP is weird on OS X, I remember having issues (back in the day) to get it running, but was mainly because OS X runs it own MySQL server etc so had conflicts. Now everything has been running smooth, the only thing is the "auto start mysql on startup" that I never got working, so I always have to start it manually, but Apache for example does start on boot..